# Can't get Laravel Beautymailer to work laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm looking to use laravel beautymailer package.

https://github.com/Snowfire/Beautymail

When i use the "normal mail" from laravel

```
$data = $request->all();

    Mail::send('emails.approveappointment', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->to($data['email'], 'John Doe')->subject('contact request');
    });
```

it works perfectly.

When i use this:

```
$data = $request->all();

    $beautymail = app()->make(\Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('emails.approveappointment', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->to($data['email'], 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
```

i get this error :

[image]

How is this possible?

I have no clue what to try since there is nearly no documentation online at all.

Only the installation, which i ran ofcourse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mail server you're trying to send through requires authentication.

Comment: Yeah where you've set up the parameters for your mail server (mailgun or whatever) you probably need to send a couple of extra parameters for the authentication information

Comment: How can it be that the normal mail function works? Does beatymail package require more parameters? And where do i set these extra parameters? The env file is working, right? since the normal laravel mail is working @aynber

Comment: How can it be that the normal mail function works? Does beatymail package require more parameters? And where do i set these extra parameters? The env file is working, right? since the normal laravel mail is working @AndyHolmes

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used the package you're using, but if the default mail system is working, and your additional package is failing with an `authentication` error, something needs to be added to the latter

Comment: For example, is the `.env` file being used by the new package?